# Sampling in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, bigdata, hadoop2, sample

New to Pyspark

I am loading a JSON file from a HDFS. It reads the data from logs one at a time.
let's say picking up date , config1d from the each log and loading it into a JSON file.

Is there a way to only load 5 or 10 percent of the data using random sampling with out loading the whole JSON file in the memory. Since loading the whole JSON file takes up more than an hour for me.

Please let me know if have more questions on it

Comment: try using `samplingRatio` parameter: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.json

Answer (score 0):

For dataframe df you can use df.sample(fraction=0.05, seed=3) to sample 5 percent.  Fraction is a number between 0 and 1, seed is optional but otherwise random.

Comment: using df.sample() , the problem still persists since i have to load the data frame and hence it will take time and memory , I am looking for some sampling thats done while creating the json file

Answer (score 0):

In Spark, it's not possible to do it without first load all the data in your memory. First, you have to load it and the do sample (transformation) as @firtree said.

Comment: Hmmm  , ok just thinking of some alternatives
Appreciate the help